# How to run Arquillian Tests on MSSQL Database?

Tags: jpa, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

My Arquillian tests run perfectly on the embbeded H2 database. I use a Jboss Managed profile.

Now, I would like to run the same tests on a SQL Server. I have the database and driver jar ready. I have also created a jboss-datasource:

```
<datasources
xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema
    http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
<datasource
    jndi-name="jdbc/TestDS_MSSQL"
    pool-name="ExampleDS"
    enabled="true"
    use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.15:1433/My_DB</connection-url>
    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>PASS</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
</datasources>
```

but I'm getting the following error message:

```
service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_microsoft_sqlserver_jdbc_SQLServerDriver (missing)
```

I'm not really sure what to do next...

Comment: kindly mention the JBOSS AS version and complete configuration file where you have defined datasources.

Comment: I'm using JBOSS AS 7.1.1.Final. The standalone.xml is the default one, since I'm running my tests on Arquillian, which downloads, unpack and start a server instance on the fly, I cannot rely on changes made on the standalone.xml.

Comment: The errors shows that you don't have proper SQL server driver on your class path, first put proper driver in your project's class path.

Answer (score 2):

Try this , This might help you out.
If you are using JBOSS 7.x then edit the datasources element in your standalone.xml file.

```
            <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/xxx" pool-name="xxx" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://ORACLE-xxx:1433;DatabaseName=xxx</connection-url>
                <driver>sqlserver2008</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>false</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>pass</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="sqlserver2008" module="com.microsoft">
                    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```